# Do I really need to manually specify all source files in cmake project?

Tags: c++, cmake

This might be a really dumb question. I'm using my `CMakeLists.txt` which is declare source files in this way(I know it isn't a good practice):

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
aux_source_directory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src DIR_SRC)
add_executable(hello "${DIR_SRC}")
```

After watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk) speaking. I know that maybe I should not use `include_directories`. But will it be lengthy and unreadable if I specify all source files manually when I call `add_executable`?

BTW, if I have some classes need to call different API on different platform. Should I use

```
if (WIN32)
    add_executable(hello SomeClassWin32.cpp SomeClass.h)
elseif (UNIX)
    add_executable(hello SomeClassLinux.cpp SomeClass.h)
endif ()
```

or just use `#ifdef`.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: The developers say yes, in that globbing is not recommended. See the note in the middle of this page: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/file.html#glob](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/file.html#glob)

Comment: How would your compiler know what files to build if you don't tell it about all of them? Magic?

Comment: If you don't want to specify every file, you can use `file(GLOB ...`, yet CMake doesn't recommend this.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Presumably by scanning a working directories and discriminating on file extension, or something like that.

Comment: As a person who has used `CMake` for 12 years now at work, specifying each file is not really an issue for me even for projects with a thousand source files and hundreds of thousands of source code lines. The reason is its not like you ever need to add 100 source files in a single day! With that said for simple example projects / development of concepts projects I do use globbing of folders.

Comment: @drescherjm So in your project you just `add_executable(hello source1.cpp source1.h source2.cpp source2.h ...)` (maybe a single file in a line?)

Comment: I usually use `CMake` variables for the source files and headers. I usually set these variables in the same `CMake` script. As for the format of how I set the variables I usually use one line per file with the closing ) on its own line. That way I comment out a line to remove a file from the list. At the end of the list if there is a folder involved in each path I have some lines with just the path commented out to make it easy to add additional entries.

Comment: @drescherjm What about to use `target_source` in `CMakeLists.txt` which is inside each sub folder. I'm inspired by [this](https://crascit.com/2016/01/31/enhanced-source-file-handling-with-target_sources/). BTW should I also add all of my header files in `target_source` at the same time?(the article's author above has mentioned this)

Comment: I am still doing things the old way. I have not used target_sources() yet. One reason is I have projects from 2008 that are still in production.

Comment: You may want to ask a completely new question about target_sources() and your concerns about the usage

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks a lot.